# Why is there memory leaks with SDL2 (2.0.14) dll?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, sdl-2, dr-memory

I am using SDL2 version [2.0.14](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php). This is the current stable version.
I noticed that any program I write with SDL2 has memory leaks. For example

```c
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main() {
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("title", 
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                        640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

This is the `main.c` file. I build it with `gcc main.c -o main.exe -lSDL2 -lSDL2main`
If I run `drmemory main.exe` this is what I get -

```
ERRORS FOUND:
      1 unique,     2 total unaddressable access(es)
      6 unique,     6 total uninitialized access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
      0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
      0 unique,     0 total handle leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
      1 unique,     1 total,     88 byte(s) of leak(s)
      1 unique,     1 total,     26 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
```

I don't see why this program has leaks at all. I tried to find out what is wrong and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494515/has-sdl2-a-memory-leak)
Although this is already answered, I don't see how this solves my issue. I want to know **why** am I having these leaks and how to fix them. Also do I need to worry about those `unaddressable` and `uninitialized` accesses diagnosed by [Dr. Memory](https://drmemory.org/).

I suspect it has to do something with the `SDL2.dll` I downloaded from [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php). I am using the `win32-x64` dll.

### **EDIT**

Here is the full 'error' details

```
Dr. Memory version 2.3.0 build 1 built on Feb  6 2020 06:07:09
Windows version: WinVer=63;Rel=;Build=9600;Edition=Professional
Dr. Memory results for pid 4868: "main.exe"
Application cmdline: "main.exe"
Recorded 118 suppression(s) from default C:\Program Files (x86)\Dr. Memory\bin64\suppress-default.txt

Error #1: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS beyond top of stack: reading 0x000000000023fb70-0x000000000023fb78 8 byte(s)
# 0 .text                                   [../../../../../src/gcc-8.1.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:132]
# 1 _pei386_runtime_relocator
# 2 __tmainCRTStartup
# 3 .l_start
# 4 KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk       +0x21     (0x00007ff902e81412 <KERNEL32.dll+0x1412>)
Note: @0:00:00.281 in thread 3800
Note: 0x000000000023fb70 refers to 600 byte(s) beyond the top of the stack 0x000000000023fdc8
Note: instruction: or     $0x0000000000000000 (%rcx) -> (%rcx)

Error #2: UNINITIALIZED READ: reading 0x000000000023eeec-0x000000000023eef0 4 byte(s) within 0x000000000023eee8-0x000000000023eef0
# 0 system call NtGdiOpenDCW parameter value #5
# 1 GDI32.dll!GetNearestColor                                +0x21f    (0x00007ff903152650 <GDI32.dll+0x12650>)
# 2 GDI32.dll!GetNearestColor                                +0x30c    (0x00007ff90315273d <GDI32.dll+0x1273d>)
# 3 GDI32.dll!CreateDCW                                      +0x12     (0x00007ff903152783 <GDI32.dll+0x12783>)
# 4 SDL2.dll!?                                               +0x0      (0x0000000073eae403 <SDL2.dll+0x10e403>)
# 5 SDL2.dll!?                                               +0x0      (0x0000000073eae781 <SDL2.dll+0x10e781>)
# 6 USER32.dll!mouse_event                                   +0x1f9    (0x00007ff90532df1a <USER32.dll+0xdf1a>)
# 7 SDL2.dll!?                                               +0x0      (0x0000000073eae91a <SDL2.dll+0x10e91a>)
# 8 SDL2.dll!?                                               +0x0      (0x0000000073eb1d9d <SDL2.dll+0x111d9d>)
# 9 SDL2.dll!?                                               +0x0      (0x0000000073e760ce <SDL2.dll+0xd60ce>)
#10 SDL2.dll!?                                               +0x0      (0x0000000073da1547 <SDL2.dll+0x1547>)
#11 main    
Note: @0:00:02.451 in thread 3800

Error #3: UNINITIALIZED READ: reading 0x000000000023f734-0x000000000023f738 4 byte(s) within 0x000000000023f730-0x000000000023f738
# 0 system call NtUserCreateWindowEx parameter value #14
# 1 USER32.dll!IsCharAlphaW                                           +0x20e    (0x00007ff905329d4f <USER32.dll+0x9d4f>)
# 2 USER32.dll!IsCharAlphaW                                           +0x436    (0x00007ff905329f77 <USER32.dll+0x9f77>)
# 3 USER32.dll!CreateWindowExW                                        +0x7d     (0x00007ff90532a03e <USER32.dll+0xa03e>)
# 4 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073eaffe9 <SDL2.dll+0x10ffe9>)
# 5 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073eb08fc <SDL2.dll+0x1108fc>)
# 6 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073e740b7 <SDL2.dll+0xd40b7>)
# 7 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073e755df <SDL2.dll+0xd55df>)
# 8 main    
Note: @0:00:02.839 in thread 3800

Error #4: UNINITIALIZED READ: reading 0x000000000023f7d4-0x000000000023f7d8 4 byte(s) within 0x000000000023f7d0-0x000000000023f7d8
# 0 system call NtUserCreateWindowEx parameter value #14
# 1 USER32.dll!IsCharAlphaW                                           +0x20e    (0x00007ff905329d4f <USER32.dll+0x9d4f>)
# 2 USER32.dll!IsCharAlphaW                                           +0x436    (0x00007ff905329f77 <USER32.dll+0x9f77>)
# 3 USER32.dll!CreateWindowExW                                        +0x7d     (0x00007ff90532a03e <USER32.dll+0xa03e>)
# 4 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073eb2b9c <SDL2.dll+0x112b9c>)
# 5 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073e7584d <SDL2.dll+0xd584d>)
# 6 main    
Note: @0:00:03.636 in thread 3800

Error #5: UNINITIALIZED READ: reading 0x000000000023f494-0x000000000023f498 4 byte(s) within 0x000000000023f490-0x000000000023f498
# 0 system call NtUserCreateWindowEx parameter value #14
# 1 USER32.dll!IsCharAlphaW                                           +0x20e    (0x00007ff905329d4f <USER32.dll+0x9d4f>)
# 2 USER32.dll!IsCharAlphaW                                           +0x436    (0x00007ff905329f77 <USER32.dll+0x9f77>)
# 3 USER32.dll!CreateWindowExW                                        +0x7d     (0x00007ff90532a03e <USER32.dll+0xa03e>)
# 4 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073eaf7fa <SDL2.dll+0x10f7fa>)
# 5 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073eafaed <SDL2.dll+0x10faed>)
# 6 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073eb099d <SDL2.dll+0x11099d>)
# 7 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073eb2c5b <SDL2.dll+0x112c5b>)
# 8 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073e7584d <SDL2.dll+0xd584d>)
# 9 main    
Note: @0:00:03.890 in thread 3800

Error #6: UNINITIALIZED READ: reading 0x000000000023f494-0x000000000023f498 4 byte(s) within 0x000000000023f490-0x000000000023f498
# 0 system call NtUserCreateWindowEx parameter value #14
# 1 USER32.dll!IsCharAlphaW                                           +0x20e    (0x00007ff905329d4f <USER32.dll+0x9d4f>)
# 2 USER32.dll!IsCharAlphaW                                           +0x436    (0x00007ff905329f77 <USER32.dll+0x9f77>)
# 3 USER32.dll!CreateWindowExW                                        +0x7d     (0x00007ff90532a03e <USER32.dll+0xa03e>)
# 4 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073eaf7fa <SDL2.dll+0x10f7fa>)
# 5 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073eafe55 <SDL2.dll+0x10fe55>)
# 6 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073eb099d <SDL2.dll+0x11099d>)
# 7 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073eb2c5b <SDL2.dll+0x112c5b>)
# 8 SDL2.dll!?                                                        +0x0      (0x0000000073e7584d <SDL2.dll+0xd584d>)
# 9 main    
Note: @0:00:03.947 in thread 3800

Error #7: UNINITIALIZED READ: reading 0x000000000023f6b0-0x000000000023f6b8 8 byte(s) within 0x000000000023f6a8-0x000000000023f6b8
# 0 system call NtUserTrackMouseEvent TRACKMOUSEEVENT post-dwFlags
# 1 SDL2.dll!?                                                                +0x0      (0x0000000073eb3bf2 <SDL2.dll+0x113bf2>)
# 2 SDL2.dll!?                                                                +0x0      (0x0000000073dcc1b7 <SDL2.dll+0x2c1b7>)
# 3 SDL2.dll!?                                                                +0x0      (0x0000000073dca237 <SDL2.dll+0x2a237>)
# 4 SDL2.dll!?                                                                +0x0      (0x0000000073dca7a8 <SDL2.dll+0x2a7a8>)
# 5 SDL2.dll!?                                                                +0x0      (0x0000000073ea90d8 <SDL2.dll+0x1090d8>)
# 6 USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW                                               +0x15c    (0x00007ff9053224fd <USER32.dll+0x24fd>)
# 7 USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW                                               +0xc2     (0x00007ff905322463 <USER32.dll+0x2463>)
# 8 USER32.dll!CallWindowProcW                                                +0x9a     (0x00007ff905323ccb <USER32.dll+0x3ccb>)
# 9 OPENGL32.dll!glDebugEntry                                                 +0x1146b  (0x00007ff8fa3928fc <OPENGL32.dll+0x428fc>)
#10 USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW                                               +0x15c    (0x00007ff9053224fd <USER32.dll+0x24fd>)
#11 USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW                                               +0xc2     (0x00007ff905322463 <USER32.dll+0x2463>)
#12 USER32.dll!MsgWaitForMultipleObjects                                      +0x141    (0x00007ff905323902 <USER32.dll+0x3902>)
#13 USER32.dll!MsgWaitForMultipleObjects                                      +0x20d    (0x00007ff9053239ce <USER32.dll+0x39ce>)
#14 USER32.dll!GetWindowLongW                                                 +0x10f    (0x00007ff905326980 <USER32.dll+0x6980>)
#15 SDL2.dll!?                                                                +0x0      (0x0000000073e73b3c <SDL2.dll+0xd3b3c>)
#16 SDL2.dll!?                                                                +0x0      (0x0000000073e75896 <SDL2.dll+0xd5896>)
#17 main    
Note: @0:00:06.599 in thread 3800

Error #8: LEAK 88 direct bytes 0x0000000002679b00-0x0000000002679b58 + 0 indirect bytes
# 0 replace_RtlAllocateHeap               [d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c:3771]
# 1 IMM32.dll!CtfImmGetTMAEFlags         +0x1b4    (0x00007ff905013b35 <IMM32.dll+0x3b35>)
# 2 IMM32.dll!ImmGetContext              +0x105    (0x00007ff905012396 <IMM32.dll+0x2396>)
# 3 SDL2.dll!?                           +0x0      (0x0000000073eaae90 <SDL2.dll+0x10ae90>)
# 4 SDL2.dll!?                           +0x0      (0x0000000073eab89b <SDL2.dll+0x10b89b>)
# 5 SDL2.dll!?                           +0x0      (0x0000000073dc8961 <SDL2.dll+0x28961>)
# 6 SDL2.dll!?                           +0x0      (0x0000000073ea90a4 <SDL2.dll+0x1090a4>)
# 7 USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW          +0x15c    (0x00007ff9053224fd <USER32.dll+0x24fd>)
# 8 USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW          +0xc2     (0x00007ff905322463 <USER32.dll+0x2463>)
# 9 USER32.dll!CallWindowProcW           +0x9a     (0x00007ff905323ccb <USER32.dll+0x3ccb>)
#10 OPENGL32.dll!glDebugEntry            +0x1146b  (0x00007ff8fa3928fc <OPENGL32.dll+0x428fc>)
#11 USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW          +0x15c    (0x00007ff9053224fd <USER32.dll+0x24fd>)

Error #9: POSSIBLE LEAK 26 direct bytes 0x00000000029c01c0-0x00000000029c01da + 0 indirect bytes
# 0 replace_malloc                    [d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c:2577]
# 1 msvcrt.dll!malloc_crt
# 2 msvcrt.dll!_setargv  
# 3 msvcrt.dll!_getmainargs
# 4 pre_cpp_init
# 5 msvcrt.dll!initterm  
# 6 __tmainCRTStartup
# 7 .l_start
# 8 KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk +0x21     (0x00007ff902e81412 <KERNEL32.dll+0x1412>)

===========================================================================
FINAL SUMMARY:

DUPLICATE ERROR COUNTS:
    Error #   1:      2

SUPPRESSIONS USED:

ERRORS FOUND:
      1 unique,     2 total unaddressable access(es)
      6 unique,     6 total uninitialized access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
      0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
      0 unique,     0 total handle leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
      1 unique,     1 total,     88 byte(s) of leak(s)
      1 unique,     1 total,     26 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
ERRORS IGNORED:
     91 potential error(s) (suspected false positives)
         (details: C:\Users\Kabir\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-main.exe.4868.000\potential_errors.txt)
     10 potential leak(s) (suspected false positives)
         (details: C:\Users\Kabir\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-main.exe.4868.000\potential_errors.txt)
    112 unique,   248 total,  34288 byte(s) of still-reachable allocation(s)
         (re-run with "-show_reachable" for details)
Details: C:\Users\Kabir\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-main.exe.4868.000\results.txt
```

Comment: It's not uncommon for libraries to do some static allocations for things that are supposed to stay alive for the full run-time of the program, and then let the operating system release such resources when the program exits.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so this is not 'actual' leak and I should not worry about it?

Comment: If the results are the same independent of how long your run your program or how much work you do in it, then it's probably a false positive.

Comment: It shows one possible memory leak but I don't see the call stack. If Dr.Memory doesn't provide it, try a profiler that can do that, e.g. Deleaker. It might happen that this is a single-time allocation that is expected. It really happens, but a call stack would definitely help a lot.

Comment: @ArtemRazin Sorry for the late reply. I added the full details I am getting from Dr.Memory.